# How can I use Prediction over clusters [R]

Tags: r, ggplot2, pattern-matching, cluster-analysis, prediction

I have a telemetry data which consist of its position and the activity of a bird. The dataset is in the csv format which I am uploading:

```
Lat. Long. Act    Date   Time
12    17   Eat    5-1-08 13:10
14    18   Rest   5-1-08 13:30
19    14   Walk   5-1-08 13:50
11    10   Rest   5-1-08 14:10
18    11   Walk   5-1-08 14:20
15    19   Walk   5-1-08 14:40
10    17   Rest   5-1-08 15:00    
....
```

I have produced ggplot (lat and long) to get the clusters over the bird path. Theory is higher the density of a cluster (in a *continuous time interval*) probability that it is eating is more.

```
plt1 <- ggplot(data = dataframe, aes(y = Lat., x = Long., colour = Act) )
```

Problem:

1. I have to find patterns (& store it) what the bird is doing after eating and for some unknown dataset (only Lat. and long is provided) I have to find the eating points in the plot based on the known patterns.

Can anyone help me in suggesting some solution or references (algorithms, libraries.. anything..) to this..?

Comment: This sounds more like a methods question for CrossValidated than a programming question for StackOverflow.

Comment: @ulfelder It is a programming question.

Comment: I guess I see it as a methods question if you're not sure what modeling or pattern-recognition function to call to accomplish the task, and a programming question if you know the function you want but are not sure how to execute it. Anyway...

Comment: In this, I want to fist make my data frame continuous  let's say in 30 minutes time interval. Then I want to find the dense clusters. Also, I have to find the eating pattern of a bird store it. Then based on that I want to predict for the "Eat" points where only lat and longs are given.

Comment: @ulfelder yes you can say that. I am confused how to tackle the problem

Comment: I would recommend looking on CrossValidated for questions about spatial pattern recognition and posting a new one there if you can't find any good leads.

Comment: @ulfelder I'll try that.. thank you. Can you help me out in this problem?

Comment: No, I don't know those methods.

Comment: cross-post: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/163223/7828